# After latest Windows 10 update, Is there a way to regain battery charging without battery disconnection?

Tags: windows, windows-10, battery, asus-laptop, charging

After updating to the latest Windows 10 update, my battery is no longer charging when the laptop is connected to power.
I have an Asus laptop which will require a major teardown to get to the battery and dis/re-connect it, which is the recommended procedure on the Internet to solve this issue.

**Is there a way to regain battery charging without battery disconnection?**

Comment: Do you have the ASUS battery software installed[?](https://superuser.com/questions/1433752/asus-laptop-starts-and-stops-charging-frequently-but-only-when-logged-into-wind#comment2163898_1433752)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Ramhound. I'm not sure, I'll check once I'm back home.

Comment: After coming home, @Ramhound, I found the *ASUS Battery Health Charging* on my laptop, changed its setting, and now my battery is charging. Thanks again for the tip. (https://www.asus.com/ca-en/support/faq/1032726/#4)